# Emacsのmultipule cursorsが使いたいのですが、設定方法がわかりません。

Tags: emacs

emacsのmultiple cursorsをインストールするとこまではできたのですが、その後の設定がよくわからずに困っています。requireとかはどのファイルに書けばいいのでしょうか？

そのあたりを詳しく書いているサイトがみあたりません。そんなことも知らないのかと思われるかもしれませんがよろしくお願いします。

**以下は~/.emacsに記述しています**

> ;; key bind (load-theme 'manoj-dark t) (define-key global-map [(S c)]
>   'kill-ring-save)
>
> ;; packcage init (require 'package) (add-to-list 'package-archives
>   '("melpa" . "https://melpa.org/packages/") t) (package-initialize)
>
> (custom-set-variables  ;; custom-set-variables was added by Custom. 
>   ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.  ;;
>   Your init file should contain only one such instance.  ;; If there is
>   more than one, they won't work right.  '(package-selected-packages
>   (quote (multiple-cursors)))) (custom-set-faces  ;; custom-set-faces
>   was added by Custom.  ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up,
>   so be careful.  ;; Your init file should contain only one such
>   instance.  ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.  )
>
> (require 'multiple-cursors) 
>   (global-set-key (kbd "C-S-c C-S-c")'mc/edit-lines)
>   (global-set-key (kbd "C->") 'mc/mark-next-like-this)
>   (global-set-key (kbd "C-<") 'mc/mark-previous-like-this)
>   (global-set-key (kbd "C-c C-<") 'mc/mark-all-like-this)

requireできているのかわかりません。
とりあえず ctrl + Shift + c → ctrl + Shift + cを押してもなにも反応しません

Answer (score 0):

**自身による投稿**

環境は以下です

> centos 
>   GNU Emacs 25.3.1

multipule cursorsを使用するにはまず **~/.emacs**に以下の構文を記述します。これを保存しemacsを再起動します。

> (require 'package) 
>   (add-to-list 'package-archives '("melpa" ."https://melpa.org/packages/") t) 
>   (package-initialize)

次にemacsの画面で下記のように入力します。multiple-cursorsのインストールがはじまるはずです。Mはメタキー

```
M-x → package-install → enter → multiple-cursors → enter
```

次に**~/.emacs**ファイルに以下の構文を追加します

> (require 'multiple-cursors)  
>   (global-set-key (kbd "C-S-c C-S-c")'mc/edit-lines)
>   (global-set-key (kbd "C->")'mc/mark-next-like-this) 
>   (global-set-key (kbd "C-<")'mc/mark-previous-like-this) 
>   (global-set-key (kbd "C-c C-<")'mc/mark-all-like-this)

---

**まとめ**
これでmultiple-cursorsが動作するはずなのですが、別の問題で動作しませんでした。emacsがshiftキーを認識しておらず私の環境では上記のキーバインドでは動作しませんでした。

しかしキーバインドの変更で動作することは確認しています。

**補足事項**

**※【重要】ターミナル上でEmacsを使っている人は、一部のキーバインドが使えないようになっているので、適宜修正してください。※**

詳しい仕組みについてはよくわからないのですが以下のサイトが参考になるようです。わたしのようにEmacsをあまり知ら無い人が苦しまないことをいのっています。
[iTerm2上のemacsで C-; C-: C-> C-< C-. C-, 記号キーバインドが入力できないのを解決する](https://joppot.info/2017/04/26/3861)